# Unable to run the specified macro

Tags: .net

This is the sample code

```
wrdApp.Run("Macro1", ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
   ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
   ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
   ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

When I am trying to run the application, @ the above line it is throwing the following error.

COM Exception: Unable to run the specified macro.

I am reading a template and then performing some operations.

Please help me

Regards

Sarayu

Answer (score -1):

Found it!

This drive me crazy for days. Here's the deal - You're calling

```
wrdApp.Run(....
```

on the WordApp object however the macro is (probably) executing against a Document. Word needs to know the ActiveDocument in order to execute. So before calling wrdApp.Run() add the following line:

```
wrdDoc.Activate()
```

This solved my problem

Comment: this is not true! I also have error when calling `Application.Run("DoEvents")`  after `wrdDoc.Activate()`